# If two subsequences converge to the same limit, is that sufficient to say that a limit exists for the sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Specifically, I've proven that for a sequence $x_n$, the subsequences $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n-1}$ converge to L. Is that sufficient to say that $x_n$ converges to L?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, there are other kinds of subsequences between odd and even. The possible duplicate's answer might address this but perhaps only after some adjustment.

Comment: @RobertSoupe The specific question asked (in question body) is about even and odd.

Comment: @NormalHuman Ah, you're absolutely right. I failed to notice the subscripts $2n$ and $2n - 1$. If I had noticed those, I would've voted "duplicate" with you, instead of skipping it. At least that's the final close reason, and not the ridiculous "off-topic."

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case the sequence does converge to $L$ because there exists $M>0$ such that $n>M\implies |x_{2n} - L|\lt \epsilon$ and there exists $N>0$ such that $n\gt N\implies |x_{2n-1}-L|\lt \epsilon$. Let $P$ = max($M,N$) and then $n\gt P\implies |x_n-L|\lt \epsilon$

In general, the result is not true. Consider a sequence {$y_n$} where $y_i=0$ for odd $i$ and $y_i=1$ for even $i$. Then the subsequences {$y_{2n}$} and {$y_{4n}$} both converge to $1$ but {$y_{n}$} does not.

Comment: What's special about OP's two sequences is: the union of sets of indexes of the two sequences is $\mathbb{N}$. The union could omit finitely many indexes and the result still holds, but if it omits an infinite set then there are counterexamples.